# Python / Django render_to_string outpu rendered as text with html entities

Tags: python, html, django

I am porting a python / Django application from:
Django==1.5.1
python version 2.6.6

to

Django==3.2
python version 3.6.8

The issue that I am having is that I have a section of code that renders to string, a particular HTML template, and then adds that to list to output elsewhere.

The actual code that produces this HTML is:

```
class AccountAdmin(SmarterModelAdmin):
   list_display = ('username', 'files_url', 'teamMembers', 'roleMemberships', 'safetyLimit', 'admin_quota', 'manager', 'enabled', 'path')
   list_filter = ['enabled', 'manager', 'accountType']
   search_fields = ['username']
   inlines = [RolesInline]
   valid_lookups = (
      'members__member__username',
      'teams__role__username',
   )
```

````
      roles = Account.objects.filter(teams__member=account).order_by('username')
      roleList = []
      for role in roles:
         link = '/admin/files/account/?teams__role__username=' + role.username
#        mylink = '<a href="{myurl}">'+role.username+'</a>'
#        linkText = format_html(mylink,myurl=link)
         linkText = render_to_string('common/contact.html', context={'URL': link, 'contact': role})
         roleList.append(linkText)
      return ', '.join(roleList)
   roleMemberships.short_description='Roles'
   roleMemberships.allow_tags=True```
````

I have added in a logging.warn to validate what comes out of the render_to_string, and it is straight HTML.

The commented out lines were something that I tried that fixed a similar issue.

common/contact.html  is:

```
<a
   href="{{ URL }}"
   {% if not contact.enabled %}
      style="text-decoration:line-through;"
   {% endif %}
>{{ contact.username }}</a>
```

However, on the final render,  It comes out like this:

<a href="/admin/files/account/?teams__role__username=abaumann"
>abaumann</a>, 
<a href="/admin/files/account/?teams__role__username=abaumann">abaumann</a>

which when run through a browser looks like this:
[image: django admin output]

I haven’t been able to find anything that references this particular issue.  I have everything else working in the admin section of the django application, and I am at a loss for why it is not  rendering as expected.

Please let me know if there is anything else that you need to see.

Answer (score 0):

I was on the right track, just had an issue with implementation.

Django backend tries to make everything secure.  As such,  the generated HTML from my template was not considered safe.  So,  using the mark_safe() function was the key.  But where to place it was the challenge.

Anytime the variable containing the HTML is modified IN ANY WAY, the "safe" flag is removed, and the variable is passed through encoding to render any HTML as text.

So the fixe is, on this line:
`return ', '.join(roleList)`

change it to:
`return mark_safe(', '.join(roleList))`

My mistake was placing the mark_safe on the linkText variable either at the time the vaiable was set, or when it was appended to the roleList.